# python- argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

Tags: python, pygame

```
from pygame import *
screen = display.set_mode((1024,768))
init()                                
shape=draw.circle(screen,(0,0,0),(80,30),15)
screen.blit(shape,(80,30))
display.flip()

quit()
```

I keep getting this error. I want to put this into my main program but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this error mean: TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517096/what-does-this-error-mean-typeerror-argument-1-must-be-pygame-surface-not-pyg)

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
screen.blit(shape, ... )
```

You don't need it.

`draw.circle()` doesn't create shape. It draws circle on screen and return circle position and size as `pygame.Rect` object.

You could use `pygame.Rect` as second argument in `blit()` but you don't need it.

```
 blit(some_image_or_surface, shape)
```

--

EDIT:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768))

pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0,0,0),(80,30),15)

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT
            running = False

pygame.quit()
```